# mypy command line option stricter than --strict

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following code in `test.py`

```
x = 1
```

Does there exist an option in `mypy` to force definition of type hints for *all* variables? `--strict` is nice, but it allows an expression like the one above.

Is there anything stricter than `--strict`?

Comment: isn't it redundant when you're type hinting `a: Class = Class()`?

Comment: Not necessarily, suppose `B` is a subclass of `A`. I could then legally do either `b: A = B()` or `b: B = B()`. Both would be fine.

Comment: Look here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#disallow-dynamic-typing or here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls

Comment: Already did... couldn't find it...